# How to disable Django's sessionid and csrftoken for a specific path

Tags: django

How is it possible to disable the creation of Session ID and CSRF Token for a specific path (e.g. /api) in django.

Comment: You can decorate the view for that URL with [`@csrf_exempt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt)

Comment: Thanks. but what about Session ID?

Comment: if you don't use `request.session`, it won't set the session cookie.  Same with CSRF...

Comment: I'm not using any of them. But django creates them an puts them in cookie for all views.